# cast std::list<X> to std::list<Y>

Tags: c++

Here's my situation. I have two classes X and Y.

X inherits from Y.

```
class X : public Y
```

I have a method defined as such:

```
void getSomethingFromList(std::list<Y> list);
```

How can I pass a list of X objects to this method like this?

```
std::list<X> xList;
getSomethingFromList((std::list<Y>)xList);
```

Comment: There is no cast that can do this. You can copy the elements of `std::list<X>` to another `std::list<Y>` but you will experience object slicing.

Comment: No, you can not - but you can have a list of `unique_ptr`s to your base object.

Comment: `std::list<X>` and ``std::list<Y>`` are completely unrelated types. There's no easy way to do that.

Comment: You cannot, you have to copy at worst, but better change interface

Comment: `std::list<std::unique_ptr<Y>>` is more what you need

Comment: @NathanOliver then it probably would be better `std::vector`, as keeping pointers in list is not a good idea.

Comment: Why don't you use a template like `template<typename T> void getSomethingFromList(std::list<T> const &list);`? Also, why does your function intended to *get* something return `void`? Why do you take the functions argument as a cop?

Comment: @Slava we have to assume there was a reason to use list in the first place

Comment: @Swordfish this would not help OP in any way

Comment: @SergeyA for objects yes, but for pointers that reason most probably does not exist anymore.

Comment: @Slava a lot of insertions/deletions in the middle and front, together with splicing, make list a good option even for pointers.

Comment: @SergeyA insertion of a pointer in middle is pretty cheap, on another side 2 indirections, too many cache misses could be much worse. And waste of memory on top of that. Anyways as I said Nathan it is probably a case, not mandatory. OP definitely should rethink if `std::list` is a proper container if using pointers

Comment: @Slava we always have to carefully profile our use case. But merging two lists is a constant time, while merging to vectors is consuming event with pointers.

Comment: @SergeyA Why not??

Answer (score 0):

The only way to that would be to use a list of (unique) pointers, rather than the objects themselves. Obviously, that would not be ideal, but such is a price we pay for virtualizations. In your case,

```
std::list<std::unique_ptr<X>> xList;
```

Comment: ok and if that case, how would you perform the casting?

Answer (score 0):

Statically typed languages impose several restrictions on such operations for ensuring type safety, and for the case of C++, you aren't simply allowed to do that (except for repacking all the elements to a new `std::list<Y>`) If you google for keywords like "c++ containers variance" you'll find several interesting articles, such as

- http://cpptruths.blogspot.com/2015/11/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c.html

> All C++ standard library containers are invariant

Java supports covariance (in addition to invariance)

- https://dzone.com/articles/covariance-and-contravariance

Languages like Scala with advanced type system actually allow you more operations (provided that you annotate parameter types here and there, following their type system design)

- https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/variances.html