# Cannot pass vector of subclass when base class required as a param

Tags: c++, casting, stdvector

I have a class `A` and its subclass `B` and a method that takes `std::vector<A>`. And I cannot make it work by passing `std::vector<B>`.

I though that if subclass `B` can be casted to `A`, I should be able to pass vector of `B`s to method that takes vector of `A`s. How can I do that properly?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A {

    public:

        A() {}
};

class B: public A {

    public: 

        B(): A() {}
};

void method(std::vector<A> a) {}

int main() {
    std::vector<B> b;
    method(b);

    return 0;
}
```

When compiled:

```
g++ ex-cast-tag.cpp -std=c++11

ex-cast-tag.cpp:22:5: error: no matching function for call to 'method'
    method(b);
    ^~~~~~
ex-cast-tag.cpp:18:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'vector<B>' to 'vector<A>'
  for 1st argument
void method(std::vector<A> a) {}
     ^
1 error generated.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use pointers instead of objects.

Comment: Template specializations with different arguments are not related, even if the arguments are related. Try making `method()` a template function.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51428853/cast-stdlistx-to-stdlisty

Comment: @Ripi2 it does not change anything. Result is the same. Compiler says `no know conversion from vector<B*> to vector<A*>`.

Comment: @Ripi2 Both the parameter type and the value passed in must be `vector<A*>`.

Comment: "Use pointers" in the sense that you can have a vector of base class pointers, and insert derived class pointers in there. You will not need `vector<B*>`, only `vector<A*>`.

Comment: closing this a dupe is rather unfortunate, as the alleged dupe is pre 2011, and answers using `enable_if`, for example, are not allowed, but are useful here.

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to use a template. For example

```
template<typename C>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<A,C>::value>
method(std::vector<C> const&a) 
{
    // assume that a[i] is an A (derived or actually the same)

}
```

Here, I have used [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) to ensure that `C` is actually `A` or derived from `A`. But you can also use [`static_assert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) instead. In this case you get nicer error messages, but the overloading behaviour of `method()` is different (i.e. when this template is considered).

Answer (score 1):

If `B` is a subclass of `A`, it does not follow that `std::vector<B>` is a subclass of `std::vector<A>`. In order to use inheritance correctly here, you need to change the function to accept a parameter of type `std::vector<A*>` then pass it a `std::vector<A*>` whose pointers all point to instances of type `B`. Alternatively, you can make the function into a template function.

Comment: Passing `std::vector<B*>` to method that takes `std::vector<A*>` does not work either. Template works.

Comment: @TomaszSzulc I edited to clarify how to do that correctly.