# Pass two derived class in a vector in function parameter

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, vector

I have my Base class and two derived class

```
class Base{
}
class Derived_1 : public Base{
}
class Derived_2 : public Base{
}
```

My problem is I have a vector composed of Base element which only have Derived_1/2 element and I would like to pass it in a function like this :

```
Void function_a( vector<Base> v){
   for(auto e : v)
     function_b(e);
}
void function_b(vector<Derived_1> v){}
void function_b(vector<Derived_2> v){}
```

Of course this code above won't work because function_b is waiting for a Derived_1/2 but I passed a Base element.
Derived_1/2 class have common member that's why I made Base class.

I dont really understand about template or virtual class but I saw that we cannot instantiate it.
Tried with boost::any and boost::variant but my project ask me to not add those library.
[Stackoverflow_question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51430486/17659599)

Comment: when you store instances of `Derived_1` or `Derived_2` in a vector of `Base` elements there is object slicing. Polymorhpism requires pointers or references (and a virtual destructor)

Comment: what exactly is the question? You need to fix the issue with slicing first. Then you can consider to change the functions to take vectors of `std::unique_ptr<Base>`.

Comment: btw the vector is almost irrelevant for the problem in the posted code. You'd have the same issues without the vector but only a single instance

Answer (score 1):

You cannot store instances of derived classes in a vector of base elements. For details I refer you to [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing). You need references or pointers for polymorphism.

Moreoever, in your code, `e` in the loop is a single element not a vector.

It seems you want to call either of the method depending on the dynamic type of the elements. Thats what virtual methods are for:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

struct Base{
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual void function() = 0;
};

struct Derived_1 : public Base{
    void function() override {}
};

struct Derived_2 : public Base{
    void function() override {}
};



void function_a( std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> v){
   for(auto& e : v)
     e->function();
}
```